# How to post to Google+?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-api, google-plus, google-plus-domains

I want to make some application (Google App Engine) which will be fetching some data from other websites and post them in one of my "collections" in Google+.

For now I have this code:
main.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import webapp2
import httplib2
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials


class UpdateChannelTask(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.add_news()

    def add_news(self):
        credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
            'my_project.json',
            (
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.write'
            )
        )
        delegate_credentials = credentials.create_delegated('my_email@gmail.com')
        http = httplib2.Http()
        http = delegate_credentials.authorize(http)
        service = build(
            'plusDomains',
            'v1', http=http)
        service.activities().insert(
            userId='me',
            preview=True,
            body={
                'object': {
                    'originalContent': 'Test, my first post in Google+!'
                },
                'access': {
                    'items': [{
                        'type': 'domain'
                    }],
                    'domainRestricted': True
                }
            }).execute()


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(
    routes=[
        (r'/update', UpdateChannelTask),
    ],
    debug=True
)
```

but this does not work, I get error

```
HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/plusDomains/v1/people/me/activities?alt=json&preview=true returned "Forbidden">
```

How can my app gain right to post to my Google+ collection?

//edit
Am I understand this [document](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/authentication/delegation) correctly? I need to have paid account "Google for Work" to solve my problem?

Everything I do I do according to [link](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/quickstart/python). In section Delegate domain-wide authority to your service account I have to go to URL https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/my_app.appspot.com and setup something. Attempt to go there gives me screen with "You need a Google for Work account for my_app.appspot.com to login. Learn more". So I need "Google for Work"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to have a Work Account. Unfortunately the Google Plus Pages API is not open to the public. You can send a request to sign up [here](https://developers.google.com/+/api/pages-signup).

That's why you get the **HTTP 403 Forbidden** error, which means that server got your request, but refused to take the action you requiered.

So you can't automatically post to Google+ without a Work account. When you have one, you can either use [moments.insert](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/moments/insert) (to be inserted programmatically), or with the [embeddable share button](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/).

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the scope 
`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.write
 https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me
for writing the post to google+ account.By authorizing google+ using this scope, you are get the authorization token to post in google+ .

Comment: Sorry It's not right answer :] I've updated question.

Comment: No you dont need to paid google account for work. Just simply add these scopes and authorize, then you will get the token , fetch the user_id using the token , then add the activity to the user google+ account. Its simply works for me. I have integrated it in my project

Comment: Everything I do I do according to [link](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/quickstart/python). In section **Delegate domain-wide authority to your service account** I have to go to URL [link](https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/my_app.appspot.com) and setup something. Attempt to go there gives me screen with "You need a Google for Work account for my_app.appspot.com to login. Learn more". So I need "Google for Work"?